# How do you create an array in OpenAPI that has exactly 3 elements (strings) and 2 of those are enums?

Tags: arrays, json, yaml, openapi

Part of the request body that I am trying to define has a "filters" field, which is an array of exactly 3 strings.

Two of the strings come from enums (different enum lists).

I've tried `oneOf` and `anyOf` but I don't think those are correct. The `allOf` option is confusing to me, but I do want "all of" the items in the `item` list to show up once.

```
filter:
 type: array
 uniqueItems: true
 items:
  allOf:
   - title: item 1
     type: string
     enum:
      - option A
      - option B
   - title: item 2
     type: string
     enum:
      - option C
      - option D
   - title: item 3
     type: string
```

When I render this, I get an enum including options A-D and I can only select one of those.

Comment: Do you want a specific order of the strings or any of the 3 items can be at any index?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the items in a particular index, OAS 3.0.x does not allow an array of items because the OAS Spec modified their definition of the JSON Schema draft-04 spec. It only allows `items` to be an object.

If you're ok with using OAS 3.1.0, the following works well for the items defined in a particular index. This is based upon JSON Schema 2020-12 which is fully compatible with OAS 3.1.0

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
paths:
  '/thing':
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          'application/json':
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/filterRequest'

components:
  schemas:
    filterRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        filter:
          type: array
          uniqueItems: true
          prefixItems:
            - title: item 1
              enum:
                - option A
                - option B
            - title: item 2
              enum:
               - option C
               - option D
            - title: item 3
              type: string
```

`// {"filter": [ "option A", "option C", "test"]}`